# Draggable left и top в %

Tags: javascript, draggable

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы позиция перемещаемого элемента `left` и `top` менялась в процентах а не пикселях.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag</p>
</div>
```

Comment: О_о а для какой задачи? На этом примере нет никакой разницы...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME для адаптивного позиционирования элементов. Родительский элемент имеет `width:100%;` следовательно `left` и `top` записанные в бд будут на разных разрешениях по разному отображаться.

Comment: Кажется, jquery тут не поможет...

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вам поможет что-то такое:

```js
draggable('#draggable')

function draggable(selector){

  let dragging;
  
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(d => {
      d.onmousedown = e => dragging = {
          el: d, 
          x: parseInt(d.style.left||0)/100 - e.x/innerWidth, 
          y: parseInt(d.style.top||0)/100 - e.y/innerHeight
      };
  });

  function dragWindow(d, e) {
      d.el.style.left = (d.x + e.x/innerWidth)*100 + '%';
      d.el.style.top = (d.y + e.y/innerHeight)*100 + '%';
  }

  addEventListener('mousemove', e => dragging && dragWindow(dragging, e));
  addEventListener('mouseup', e => dragging = null)
}
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  position:absolute;
  border:solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag</p>
</div>
```